# Php if else logic Block runs no matter what?

Tags: php, email, variables, if-statement

So, Writing this script, and now I do get the correct email, with the old IP address from the database, and the new address from the script.  My problem now, is that wether the old ip address and the current are the same or different, the email sends.  This script will run every minute to check for dynamic ip address changes, so I don't really want an email every minute.  My goal is to have it send the email ONLY if the last posted IP is DIFFERENT from the one discovered.  Now, the email is sending wether the IPs are different or not.  Everything else works.  The email sends fine, and everything else works perfectly.  The only problem is using logic to decide when to send the email. (When the new and old IPs are different.)

When the script gets there ip from the database, it looks like 123.123.123.123.  The IP from the http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php also looks like 123.123.123.123.  (***Example) But if the database says 123.123.123.123, and the current is  134.134.134.134, it should send the email.

In the comparison, I've tried !=, ==, and I've tried putting the mail block in the then and else sections.  Could the problem be caused by different data types?  Is the $new_ip a string while $old_ip is an integer?    Im only 14, so... Yea.

```
 <?php
    //Get IP
    $new_ip = file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php');
    //Connect to SQL
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    //Select database
    mysql_select_db("ip_changes") or die(mysql_error());
    //Get Date Info
    $date = date("D M Y");
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    //Get last inserted IP
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ip ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 1');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
    $old_ip = $row['current_ip'];
    echo $old_ip;
    //Generate SQL query
    $sql="INSERT INTO ip (date, time, current_ip) VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$new_ip')";
    //Execute SQL
    mysql_query($sql);
    //Get latest IP
    //$lastip = mysql_query(SELECT $selected FROM ip ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

    if ($old_ip == $current_ip)
    {

    }

    else {

    //Set Mail Settings
    $to = "justinmarmorato@gmail.com";
    $subject = "IP Address Change";
    $from = "no-reply@http://mar-remote-net.dns2.us";
    $headers = array (
    "From:" . $from,
    "Content-Type: Text/HTML"
    );
    //Create email
    $finalmessage = <<< EOT
    Hello! This is an automated message from the IPMS. An IP address change has been detected.
    <html>
    <style>
    table, th, td
    {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-color:grey;
    }
    </style>
    <table class='table'>
    <tr>
    <td>Old IP</td><td>New IP</td><td>Time Detected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$old_ip</td><td>$new_ip</td><td>$date  $time</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>
    EOT;
    mail($to,$subject,$finalmessage,  implode("\r\n", $headers));
    mail('justinmarmorato@gmail.com', 'Hello!', implode("\r\n", $headers));


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: var_dump($old_ip) and var_dump($current_ip), will tell you what datatype you're dealing with in both instances, however, I can't see it being different, if theyre pulling from the same source

Comment: Maybe `$new_ip` ends in a newline. Try `$new_ip = trim($new_ip);`

Comment: are you storing your ip address by converting `INET_ATON()` ?

Comment: Where are you declaring/setting `$current_ip`? I do not see it in your code, other than in the if, so right now your if is `if ('134.134.134.134' == )`. You probably want - `if ($old_ip == $new_ip)`

Comment: Looks like $current_ip is never set. I think you mean to test against $new_ip

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say `$new_ip` instead of `$current_ip` in your `if` statement?

`$current_ip` doesn't appear to be set anywhere -- if that is the case `$current_ip` will always be unset and will never be equal to `$old_ip`.

Comment: Sorry, when I said current IP I meant $new_ip

Comment: i changed the second var to $new_ip, but I'm still having the same problem.  without the echo $old_ip, and with var_dump($old_ip) var_dump($new_ip) the output is    string(15) "123.123.123.123" string(167) "184.6.216.163 "      (the 123.123... is new)

Comment: It looks like the value of what I believe is `$old_ip` (the 184.6.216.163 value) is padded with spaces -- one solution would be to change your condition to `if (trim($old_ip) == trim($new_ip))`, but you might also want to change the way you are storing IP addresses to avoid the padding (this would mean changing the column type in the database to, for example, `CHAR(15)`).